# Getting Online Users using Session Files

Tags: php, session

I am trying to find out the number of users online for my site by calculation the total session files created so as to decrease database acess. Can you please throw some light as to how can i do that?
And is it possible to access the data stored in those files(for e.g User ID) so as to find Who's Online.

Comment: I would recommend a good analytics solution, such as Google Analytics or Piwik

Answer (score 1):

Count the number of session files on the server:

```
$dh = opendir(session_save_path());
$users = 0;
while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
    if (($file != '.') && ($file != '..')) {
        $users++;
    }
}
closedir($dh);
$online = $users;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the total number of users who are on your website or do you want the TOTAL number of the users who have visisted id?

The number of your session files isn't equal to the number of the current users. The session doesn't end when user leaves your web site.

A database solution should be better; Also think about a Google Analytics Solution. Google Analytics track the navigation of the users on your website.